# Developing in local environment when using a CDN

Tags: wordpress, cdn

I'm pretty new to CDN. I found a [good free service](https://statically.io/) that matches my needs in developing Wordpress (and also has a plugin for it). I already tried it on a remote project and it works.

Now, I usually develop websites in a local environment (`http://my-project.test:9000`) then I push to production on final domain (`https://my-project.com`).

Well, I don't understand how to work in a local environment with a CDN.
For instance, I tried configuring the plugin in local but it says needs https (never had to need to install an ssl certificate in local development). A CDN always needs HTTPS?

Also, in my head I should be able to use the same CDN key for 2 domain (for example the 2 above: one for local and one for production) so the static assets are "shared" for the 2 Wordpress installations.

So in general I'm really confused: how developing in local environment when you use a CDN?